# Definition of PATH

Tags: discussion, tags

I have just looked at the [path](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path) wiki. It covers the meaning of path as the shell environment variables used to find things e.g. executables in $PATH man pages in $MANPATH

However path is also the name used to define the location of a file in the role system e.g. it is the team used in [Apple's Filesystem programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3-SW6)

I have edited the wiki to add that definition as a note.

Should we

1) Restrict the tag to the PATH environment variable as per the wiki and edit the questions to remove tags

2) Edit the wiki to make the file name more prominent?

And while on $PATH we need a canonical answer as how to set it. This [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/121021/237) seems a base is there a better start elsewhere (possibly also on a SuperUser question)

Answer (score 1):

I'm of a mind to make it a synonym to [command-line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-line) when would anyone have experience in one, they have to have experience in the other. By lumping things together tag clouds and rep and badged make the site better.

Having a tag for any little aspect of command line programming / environment seems counter productive since the search tool can expose path questions extremely well with or without that tag.

Big thanks for the edit to the tag wiki and the attention here.

Comment: The edit on the wiki is temporary I/we need to do 1 or 2. If 2 then a very large edit